# How to click on element from select list with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a automation on some website with puppeteer and I have a trouble with that when I try to click on element inside select list.

All I found about that after some google search is to select an item but only when the list is inside "select" element.
My problem is that the HTML I try to automate is inside a 'div':

```
<div class="dropdown open dropdown--gray">
  <div class="dropdown__header">
     <div class="dropdown__field">other</div>
     <div class="dropdown__opener">
        <span class="icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown__list">
    <div class="dropdown__list-item selected">other</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.org</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.co.uk</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.net</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.gov</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.de</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.fr</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.nl</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.com</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.be</div>
    <div class="dropdown__list-item">.jpg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
await page.click('div.dropdown__field');
const elementHandle4=await page.$$("div.dropdown__list-item");
await elementHandle4[8].click();
```

but actually its not click on the element.
When I open manually the list after this code ran, I see that its scrolled down the scroller of the list but not clicked on the element.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
await page.click('.dropdown__field');
await page.click('.dropdown__list > div:nth-child(8)');
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like the problem in the viewport because it works correctly and selects the '.nl' option without any scrolling with the following script:

```
(async () =>  {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://userinyerface.com/game.html');
    await page.click('.dropdown__field');
    await page.click('.dropdown__list > div:nth-child(8)');
})();
```

But it will not work if I remove the `defaultViewport: null` property

Comment: I have already tired this.
But it make the same as described in the post.

Comment: Notify message @Yevhen

Comment: @GuyCohen
Could you, please, provide the link to try it?
Try scroll to the element before clicking.


`await page.$$eval('.dropdown__list > div', divs => divs[8].scrollIntoView());`

Comment: Its scrolls the whole website down , but still doesnt work.

The link is :
https://userinyerface.com/game.html

I try to automate the fill of the fields.

the problem is with "other" list.

@yevhen

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to see that element to trigger click event. First, you must scroll to the position of the element to see the element then trigger the click event.

---

It works for me

```
const ListItemIndex = 10, ListItem = document.querySelector(`.dropdown__list > div:nth-child(${ListItemIndex})`);
document.querySelector(".dropdown__list").scroll({ behavior: 'smooth', top: ListItem.offsetTop });
ListItem.click()
```

Comment: How can I scroll down inside the list view? when I try to scroll down , it scrolls my window.

Comment: Notify message @Abdulsamet

Comment: For scroll, you need to run and wait a little this JavaScript code with evaluate method: `document.querySelector(".dropdown__field").scroll({ behavior: 'smooth', top: 250 // List item top position });`

Comment: New solution works for me, so can you check answer again?

Comment: Because its Puppeteer is suppose to be async and await etc.

So what I tried as your solution is:

`await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(.dropdown__list > div:nth-child(8)``)
         );
         await page.evaluate(() =>
         document.querySelector(".dropdown__list").scroll({ behavior: 'smooth', 
         top: document.querySelector(`.dropdown__list > div:nth-child(8)`).offsetTop })
         );
         await page.click('.dropdown__list > div:nth-child(8)');'

But it didnt work.

@abdulsamet

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question to yours. In my case the HTML looked like this:

```
<select id="locationIdentifier" name="..." class="..." title="...." size="....">
    <option value="..." selected="selected">CITY NAME Station, CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME City Centre</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME, City Of</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME Airport, CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME East, CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME North, CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME NorthWest, CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME South, CITY NAME</option>
    <option value="...">CITY NAME West, CITY NAME</option>
</select>
```

I have removed all the irrelevant class names and attributes, replacing them with `...` for brevity.

What I wanted here was to select the second option from the list, which is:

```
<option value="...">CITY NAME</option>
```

It is the second option, so this will work, but it isn't ideal:

```
await page.click('select#locationIdentifier > option:nth-child(2)');
```

What happens if some change is made on the server side resulting in a different ordering? This could be hard to detect with an automated system like Puppeteer, and might lead to discontinuous data - assuming you are doing this to scrape data, which you then wish to analize.

A better approach is this:

```
const index = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('select#locationIdentifier > option');

    for(let index = 0; index < elements.length; ++ index) {
        const text = elements[index].innerText;

            if(text === 'CITY NAME') {
                return index + 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    });

    if(index === -1) {
        // Error
        console.log(`Error: Failed to find CITY NAME option`);
    }
    else {
        const tmpString = 'select#locationIdentifier > option:nth-child(' + index + ')';
        await page.click(tmpString);
    }
```

The addition of `+ 1` to the index is because the HTML indexes from 1 in `nth-child`, whereas iterating through the elements obtained from `querySelectorAll` obviously starts from 0.